# CSS Flexible background

Tags: html, css

This should be simplest thing ever but I couldn`t figure it out.

```
<div style="width:auto;background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">Example</div>
```

All I want is that background of this DIV should be big as much as the text in it. It`s like when I change "Example" to "Example of DIV" it should get bigger. I mean it should be big as much big as the text in it. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could either add a `float` CSS property, or better, `display: inline-block` or even `display: inline`. This way the DIV will have a flexible width.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
display: inline-block;
```

`inline-block` allows you to add `padding/margin` if required.